# Python convert stereo .flac to mono

Tags: python, audio, channel, flac

I am struggling with manipulation of audio channels in Python. Specifically, how to convert stereo .flac into mono .flac file in Python?

I know this method:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#stereomonostream
but i am looking for something which can be done directly in Python.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples) package?

You can install it with `pip install ffmpeg-python`. And this might solve your problem:

```py
import ffmpeg
ffmpeg.input('stereo.flac').output('mono.flac', ac=1).run()
```

There are some [examples](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples) in the GitHub repository.

Another option could be to use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i stereo.flac -ac 1 mono.flac', shell=True)
```

Be careful when using [shell=True](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).